# How do I consolidate all my partitions into one partition usable for Bootcamp?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, core-storage, fusion-drive

I've been having an issue with Bootcamp recently after I deleted my Windows disk due to a driver issue that was unfixable. I figured I would just do a fresh install of Windows, but little to my knowledge this would be the most aggravating thing I've ever had to deal with on my Mac.

It took me some time, but I was able to fix all the stray partitions in Disk Utility:[image]

but annoyingly, I still get this error:
[image]

After doing extensive reading apropos of similar issues, I've come to the conclusion that I am only able to solve this by formally wiping my physical disk so that all the partitions are one cohesive unit.
How can this be done? Here is my diskutil list:

```
    Mikes-iMac:~ MikeDang$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         24.0 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            23.6 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Mac                     998.2 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s4
```

The partition I am currently using is disk1s2, Apple_Boot Mac. Am I correct in assuming my best bet is to break down my internal disk and reinstate a clean OS X installation, and from there download a Windows ISO and run bootcamp?

I've been searching for a solution to this issue for epochs, if anyone could help I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Explain? I'm not very familiar with drive management through non-windows utilities.

Comment: The default layout at delivery: disk0s2 and disk1s2 are configured as a 1020 GB Fusion Drive (mounted as one virtual volume disk2/Macintosh HD)

Comment: Is there a way to fix that? To be honest don't mind having jacked up disk management as long as I can get my windows boot up and running.

Comment: What is the solution to this? Do I just unmount and GPT destroy one of the recovery partitions?

Comment: Also, I see what you are saying about the fusion drive being separated. Is there a way to, well, fuse the drives back together?

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with that as long as the end result is 1 OS X partition and 1 Windows partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode and open Disk Utility. Repartition each disk to one partition, GUID partition table and OS X Extended (Journaled).
- Exit Disk Utility, open Terminal in the menubar > Utilities
- Enter `diskutil list` to get the device identifiers of the SSD (24 GB) and the HDD (1 TB) (probably disk0 and disk1 with the main volumes disk0s2 and disk1s2)
- Enter the following to rebuild your Fusion Drive

  ```
  diskutil cs create Fusion disk0s2 disk1s2 #use the dev identifiers found previously
  diskutil cs list #take a note of the Logical Volume Group UUID (lvgUUID)
  diskutil coreStorage createVolume lvgUUID jhfs+ "Mac" 0g #use the lvgUUID found above here (something like 28394BA0-AC56....)
  ```
- Exit Terminal and install OS X/macOS from the Utilities window
- After several reboots configure OS X/macOS.
- Upgrade to Sierra (or an older system) if necessary/possible.
- Open Boot Camp Assistant and install Windows

Comment: You're seriously a lifesaver. If all goes well, you won't be seeing me again.

Comment: Ran into a little issue. How do I repartition both disks to one partition? Since they're separate instances, I can't find a way to interact with both of them?

Comment: @MikeDang That's the `diskutil cs create Fusion disk0s2 disk1s2`step

Comment: Never mind, I've just gotten the fusion drive fused and am currently reinstalling OS X. I offer my utmost gratitude.